# Heap intensive c++ program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, fragmentation

I am working on a Pattern searching program that continuously allocates and deallocates from the heap. The program is intended to be very conscious about memory usage so when I'm done with memory it needs to be freed to the OS. With that being said I have done extensive memory leak detection and found all of the leaks that appear on the CRT dump log, with some help from the Visual Leak detector from Visual Studio and WinDbg for stack tracing.

The major problem is that the more heap activity that occurs in the processing of a file, the more I am left with this chunk of memory that is not freed to the OS, but neither is it showing as a leak after program terminate. I grab the program's resource usage using these lines of code:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
PListType physMemUsedByMe = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
return physMemUsedByMe/1000000.0f;
```

This returns the amount of memory in MB the program is using and I make this call right before the program exits. I can have zero memory leaks but up to 500 MB of this left-over data. Not sure if this stuff is somehow sitting on the stack or is this heap fragmentation?  I do use STL maps and vectors but I clean them up properly if I use pointers.

I have been doing detective work for quite awhile and I am really not coming up with answers using forums like this so I wanted to ask my question specifically.  Any help goes a long way. It doesn't matter if i'ts just a guess, I just need some brainstorming outside of my own head LOL. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any global or local static variables? They are not destructed until after the `main` function have returned (i.e. after your check). Also, maybe the amount you get back also includes the executable program and all mapped DLLs as well? And that's besides the answer from John Zwinck.

Comment: This is the way memory allocation works.  When you free memory it becomes available to be reallocated within the same process, but it is not released back to the OS until the process exits.  But this is also largely a non-issue in a modern virtual-memory OS, for most of that unused memory associated with your process will end up swapped out if there is any pressure on physical memory.  But that memory absolutely *is* released when the program exits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That looks like an answer not a comment.

Comment: Thanks, @NathanOliver, and apparently John Zwinck thinks so, too.  I don't see a need to repeat his answer.

Comment: I do have global and static variables which are deallocated properly and would not build over time.  I thought for a while maybe writting to a log file would cause issues but then I removed logging and the same build up occurs...

Comment: It can't be "sitting on the stack", because stack is pretty much empty "right before the program exits".

Comment: @JohnBollinger So John are you saying that if I delete a vector and it does not get released back to the OS and then I allocate another vector, theoretically I could be using that block that was never released to the OS for my new vector?

Answer (score 4):

Just because you free memory does not mean that it is immediately returned to the operating system.  Your standard library likely has a pile of memory that it has obtained from the OS but which is not current in use in your program.  This is not leaked memory, and it is usually not a problem in practice.

Comment: Say for example I want to run a program that can only have 4 GB allocated to it at one time and this memory increases and increases over time.  Eventually I will not have enough memory to run my program.  The nature of my program is that it can run for days at a time and i'm afraid not getting the memory released to the OS could cause eventual paging...

Comment: @user3734523 The memory you free may still stay *mapped* to your process, it doesn't mean it's not available for other processes. If the operating systems deems it necessary it will unmap the pages from your process and give to other processes.

Comment: @user3734523: This is the sort of thing that it's better not to worry about too much in advance.  Write your code, run it, and see what actual problems you have.  Then solve those.

Comment: @user3734523, moreover, once you deallocate memory, it is available to serve future allocation requests.  You should not see the overall process usage exceed very much the maximum it ever needs to have at once.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I can watch the memory usage drop as I deallocate vectors but why does some memory stay attached( mapped) to the program.  Why do some things release to the OS and why do same stay.  Is this some sort of memory caching that stl containers do?

Comment: @user3734523: You may want to read about `sbrk()` on Unix for an example of how it can work.  Point being, only certain deallocations can release all the way back to the OS.  But this is not a problem most of the time.